# overwriting the .txt file after user edit it C++

Tags: c++

i want to let user edit the txt file and ItemID is a unique character, i wanted to do checking if user key in a similar ItemID existed in the system, an error will appear.

but after i do testing by keying in an Item ID that already exists, it successfully prompt "ItemID already exists in stock database"
but when i tried to key in another ItemID not existing in the system, nothing happens, it won't show "returning to main menu" or exit to the main menu.

please advise

```
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:

        while (true)
        {
            if (duplicate == true)
                {
                    system("clear");
                    cout << "\E[1;32m" <<itemID << "\E[0m already exists in the stock database!" << endl;
                    cout << "Please enter a unique Item ID that is not used yet" << endl;

                cout << "\E[1;32mItem ID:\E[0m\t" << stockVectorTemp[vectorChoice - 1].getItemID() << endl;
                cout << "\E[1;32mDescription:\E[0m\t" << stockVectorTemp[vectorChoice - 1].getItemDesc() << endl;
                cout << "\E[1;32mTotal Quantity:\E[0m\t" << stockVectorTemp[vectorChoice - 1].getTotalQty() << endl << endl;

                     }
                     duplicate = false;

             cout << logo_EditStock << endl;
                     cout << "Please enter new ItemID: ";
                     getline(cin, input);

             for (int i = 0; i < stockVector.size(); i++) 
             {
                if (stockVector[i].getItemID() == itemID)
                    stockVector[i].setItemID(input);

                                duplicate = true;
                    writeStockDatabase();
                 //  cout << "Returning to main menu..." << endl << endl;
                     }
                    if (!duplicate)

                     break;
        }

        cout << "Returning to main menu..." << endl << endl;
```

break;

Comment: I believe you're missing a `}` in the vicinity of `duplicate = true;`. You need to pay more attention to indentation.

Comment: As per you code, duplicate will always be set to true, irrespective of your any conditions. Please check the code appearing in the question again..have you missed anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot an opening brace to the `if()` statement. And as the comments pointed out, you should improve your formatting:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stockVector.size(); i++)
{
    if (stockVector[i].getItemID() == itemID)
    {
        stockVector[i].setItemID(input);
        duplicate = true;
        writeStockDatabase();
        //  cout << "Returning to main menu..." << endl << endl;
    }
    if (!duplicate)
        break;
}
```